# Limiting output amperage on an arc furnace

Tags: amperage

we have built an electrical arc furnace from a couple of old arc welders. We are outputting around 200 A at 30 volts. However, sometimes it will decide to draw more amps than what our 400 A rectifier can handle (which converts the AC output into DC for a more efficient arc). Is there a circuit or a device that would control the output so that it won't go above 200 A but maintain roughly the same voltage?

Comment: Your question asks if there is a way to defeat ohms law. Sadly (or probably thankfully) there isn't.

Comment: I don't know much about this as you can tell but isn't there a way of detecting the extra amperage being drawn and then kicking in a resistor or something similar?

Comment: But that will never maintain the same voltage.